# How to minify and bundle css code with media query for safari

Tags: css

I am using safari browser hack for my css:

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
@media{
.safari_only { 
    color:#0000FF; 
    background-color:#CCCCCC; 
    }
  } 
}
```

but my code is not getting minified and bundled using visual studio bundler and minify. Can someone help me on this

Comment: Your css is not valid, you have @media twice, remove the inner media and brackets.

Comment: This the media query when you want your code to work only in safari browser

Comment: Maybe try an alternative browser hack, one without nested `@media` blocks? There's a list of options here: https://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html#safari